# Drarry Harry Potter fan fiction with Draco finding Harry after a breakdown unable to tie his shoes

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, drarry

I remember finding a really good Harry Potter fan fiction. It’s a Harry/Draco ship (Drarry), and it starts off with Draco finding Harry after a breakdown, unable to tie his shoes. I believe it was on archive of our own but I can’t remember

Comment: Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11922/58193) and [edit] in some more details? For example, this is very sparse so could you tell us some more details about the plot? Also do you know where you read this? Do you know when you read it?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be [Sensitive Touch](https://archiveofourown.com/works/16203023) by Raserwolf:

> When Draco Malfoy encounters a struggling and frustrated Harry desperately trying to tie his shoes after a meltdown in the Great Hall, his curiosity regarding the incident leads him to seek the help of the two people closest to Harry: Ron and Hermione.

Comment: How did you find it?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots It actually only took one Google search: `site:archiveofourown.com harry potter tie shoes`. This exact summary is what's shown for two of the results on the first page near the bottom.

Comment: ^_^ Cool. I was just curious, because I also did a few searches, and I failed to come up with it. I'm always happy to refine my technique.